# Error calling method of object except inside foreach block

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have an array of objects that are behaving very strangely. I can run the method if I put it inside a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($options['image']->images as &$image) {
    var_dump($options['image']->images[0]->src('small'));
}
```

returns:

```
string 'files/small/test.jpg' (length=20)
```

However, the same var_dump outside the foreach loop:

```
var_dump($options['image']->images[0]->src('small'));
foreach ($options['image']->images as &$image) {
    var_dump($options['image']->images[0]->src('small'));
}
```

returns

```
Error: Call to a member function src() on a non-object
```

I've run some tests which are interesting:

```
**Get Class**
echo get_class($options['image']->images[0]);
foreach ($options['image']->images as &$image) {
    var_dump($options['image']->images[0]->src('small'));
}
```

returns:

```
Image
```

And:

```
**Get Class Methods**
var_dump(
    get_class_methods($options['image']->images[0])
);
foreach ($options['image']->images as &$image) {
    var_dump($options['image']->images[0]->src('small'));
}
```

returns:

```
array
  0 => string '__construct' (length=11)
  1 => string 'src' (length=3)
  2 => string 'makeThumb' (length=9)
  ...
```

I cannot see any reason why the object outside the foreach block would be having any issue. It may be worth noting that the $options array itself comes from a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($option_goups as $options)
```

Comment: Are you sure that there's nothing else in that first `foreach` loop?

Comment: There was: echo $this->Html->image($image->src('small')); but I can take it out and there's no difference.

Comment: Somehow the `$image` gets turned into an object inside the loop, because it's a string before you go in.

Comment: No, it's an object of type "Image" as demonstrated with var_dump(get_class($options['image']->images[0])); (note the get_class function call inside the var_dump)

Comment: Of course, that wasn't very clear so I've edited that part of the question :)

Comment: In the example you provided where you get the error, you first dump it outside of the loop and then dump it again inside the loop. Is it possible that calling the `src` function multiple times causes an error? In other words, do you still get an error if you **only** call it outside of the loop and **not** inside the loop?

Comment: Also, does it still work inside of the loop if you change `&$images` to `$images` in the loop condition? If so, that's a clue that something in the loop is changing it before you dump it.

Comment: @Travesty3 1) The second call to src() never gets called because execution stops at the fatal error. 2) Yes, it works inside the loop whether I assign by value or reference.

Comment: The point of me asking that first question is that perhaps the ***second*** call is causing the fatal error. I'm not sure if you would still see the output of the first `var_dump` if the second causes a fatal error. I'm thinking that you probably would, but it's worth checking...

Comment: @Travesty3 The line number associated with the fatal error (which I neglected to post, my appologies) indicates that the first call is causing the fatal error. Regardless, I've run it without the loop and the fatal error persists.

Comment: There has got to be something going on that's not shown in your example above. There's no reason that dumping a variable outside of a loop would cause a fatal error, but doing the exact same thing inside a loop would work.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://codepad.org/uTfeLEsQ) similar to yours. If you can modify it to show the same problem you're having, share it here. Perhaps then I can help.